# Mocha/Nightmare test failing but still waiting for timeout

Tags: mocha.js, nightmare

I'm running this test (simplified), which fails as expected ... but despite the failure, it still waits for the full 20 second timeout. How can I make it fail immediately?

```
it("should fail before timeout", function (done) {
      var nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true })
        .goto(url)
        .evaluate(function () {
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // this point is reached, and then the test just waits 
          // 20 seconds before finally failing
          throw "Fail" 
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error using `mocha`. Instead of throwing, `then` should call done with an `Error` object. (also replaced `throw "Fail"` with `throw new Error("Fail")`)